# Use CanCan to limit specific parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permissions, cancan

Can CanCan be used to limit which parameterized views a user can access?

We produce images that users buy individual access to.

For instance:

Bob has access to images 1, 3, and 4.
Joe has access to images 2 and 4.
Steve has access to image 5.

The url would be something like `site.com/images/1`.

Is there a way I can restrict which number (parameter) of a view a user can view? With or without CanCan?

I'm using Rails 3.2.1

Thanks

Comment: "Can CanCan" - hmm, how do I make a woodchuck joke out of this? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example from one of my projects.

#### classes

```
class App
  has_many :app_ownerships
end

class User
  has_many :app_ownerships
end

class AppOwnership
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :app


end
```

#### somewhere in ability.rb

```
can :read, App do |app|
  # find all ownerships with at least read-only access (access_level == 1)
  active = app.app_ownerships.select do |o|
    o.app_id == app.id && o.user_id == user.id && o.access_level >= 1
  end
  active.length > 0
end
```

#### somewhere in app_controller.rb

```
def show
  @app = App.find params[:id]
  authorize! :show, @app # throws exception if not authorized

  ...
end
```

Hope you can use this snippet for your needs.

Comment: Thanks! And I hope the wood chuck joke comes to you.  It has escaped me to this point